# normsinv function does not shows accurate result

Tags: excel, statistics

for confidence intervals, i am  using  normsinv function, for instance

for 95%  confidence interval, we know that alpha is  0.05,  so we  have

```
=NORMSINV(0.05/2)
```

which is   `-1.959963985` if we round it is exactly 1.96, for 99% interval, we have alpha=0.01  , so we have

```
=NORMSINV(0.01/2)  which is equal to  -2.575829304  rounded as 2.58,
```

but now let us consider 90% confident ,alpha is equal to 0.1

```
=NORMSINV(0.1/2)
```

which is equal to -1.644853627, if we round  we still get 1.64 instead of  1.65 , which is  reason of this ?

Comment: what did you use for rounding? when you round -1.959963985 to 2 digits you get -1.96 not -1.95

Comment: sorry it  was typo sure

Comment: did you use Excel round()  function you can use roundup() if you need to force the second digit to add 1

Comment: i found in book that  1.645  is correct result, just 1.65 is used, thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is correct when you use 2 decimal digits 1.644853627 become 1.64